# Adding elevation from geoserver in Cesium.JS

Tags: geoserver, cesium

I'm trying to view elevation data loaded from Geoserver on cesium globe. But the added elevation is viewed as 2D layer on the globe. [image]

My Code:

```
import Viewer from "cesium/Source/Widgets/Viewer/Viewer";
import WebMapServiceImageryProvider from "cesium/Source/Scene/WebMapServiceImageryProvider";
this.viewer = new Viewer(this.cesiumContainer);

var provider = new WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
  url : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc_roads/wms?',
  layers : 'nyc_roads:DEM_Maharashtra',
  parameters : {
    transparent : 'true',
    format : 'image/png'
}
});
this.viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(provider);
```

Do I need to change the function to view it on 3D. Please help.